# Build Path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

After importing my existing GWT project to Eclipse getting the following error.

Project 'TestUI' is missing required source folder: 'TestMgr/nocache/js.gwt.xml'.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your module gwt.xml. You should ensure the entry point classpath is correct

```
<!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
<entry-point class="com.me.myproject.client.TestUI" />
```

And check that you added the appropriate packages to your module

```
<!-- Adding package to this gwt module -->
<source path="client" />
<source path="shared" />
```

If everything is fine with the module, could you be more specific about where that error happens ? When launching your project ? In Eclipse warnings ?